# How can I create a table with decimal aligned and decimal autofilled numbers?

Tags: tables, siunitx, alignment

I have a table containing numbers with a variable number of decimal digits. I want that these numbers:

1. are aligned at the decimal point
2. if they have less decimal digits than the maximum one, the missing ones are automatically filled with 0s

I'm using `siunitx` package to align at the decimal number. With a code like

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=2.2]}
    \hline
    {Lorem} & {Ipsum} \\
    \hline
    1,2     & 3,4     \\
    5,67    & 8,9     \\
    1,2     & 3,45    \\
    67,89   & 12,34   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I'm able to create this table:

[image]

but what I want is like this other one:

[image]

I'm using `siunitx` because I used it in the past and I would prefer going on with it, but if there is a better package I can use it as well.

Comment: round-mode=places, round-precision=2 either using \seisetup or S[...].  See page 22 of the siunitx manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JohnKormylo has already noted in a comment, you can keep using the machinery of the `siunitx` package -- just add the options `round-mode=places` and `round-precision=2`.

Having to write

```
S[table-format=2.2,round-mode=places,round-precision=2]
```

repeatedly can become very tedious very quickly. If you find yourself in such a bind, simply define a new column type, say,

```
\newcolumntype{T}{S[table-format=2.2,round-mode=places,round-precision=2]}
```

and use it in various `tabular` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{T}{S[table-format=2.2,round-mode=places,round-precision=2]}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{TT}
    \hline
    {Lorem} & {Ipsum} \\
    \hline
    1,2     & 3,4     \\
    5,67    & 8,9     \\
    1,2     & 3,45    \\
    67,89   & 12,34   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks (to @JohnKormylo too), it does exactly what I need. Just a note if anyone else needs this - if there are also integers and empty decimals are needed for them, you can add `round-integer-to-decimal` to the options.